# EIP1559. Transaction type 0 and type 2

Tags: mining, fees, london

After the activation of the London hard fork, EIP1559 proposed a new type of transaction - type 2. Such transactions have a base fee that will be burned, and maxPriorityFeePerGas, which incentivizes miners to include this transaction in the block. In other words, the miner only gets maxPriorityFeePerGas*gas_amount. transaction fees.

What about transaction type 0? It just has a standard gasPrice field. Does this mean that in such transactions nothing is burned from the fee, and the miner receives the entire fee for the transaction?

Answer (score 1):

> The new type of transaction is called a “type 2 transaction,” and canonical transactions are called a “type 0 transaction” – and don’t ask what happened to type 1 transaction

https://2miners.com/blog/ethereum-london-hardfork-what-does-eip-1559-change/

EDIT: Thanks to @clementwalter, see https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2930#definitions

> a new EIP-2718 transaction is introduced with TransactionType 1.

Comment: actually type 1 is access list transactions:

0=legacy ;  1=access list (eip 2930) ; 2=dynamic fee (eip 1559)

Comment: Wow, TIL, can you write it as an answer please?

Answer (score 1):

Transactions types are described, e.g. in the latest EIP (1559) sepc, see https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1559.md#specification and in short

```
from typing import Union, Dict, Sequence, List, Tuple, Literal
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

@dataclass
class TransactionLegacy:
    signer_nonce: int = 0
    gas_price: int = 0
    gas_limit: int = 0
    destination: int = 0
    amount: int = 0
    payload: bytes = bytes()
    v: int = 0
    r: int = 0
    s: int = 0

@dataclass
class Transaction2930Payload:
    chain_id: int = 0
    signer_nonce: int = 0
    gas_price: int = 0
    gas_limit: int = 0
    destination: int = 0
    amount: int = 0
    payload: bytes = bytes()
    access_list: List[Tuple[int, List[int]]] = field(default_factory=list)
    signature_y_parity: bool = False
    signature_r: int = 0
    signature_s: int = 0

@dataclass
class Transaction2930Envelope:
    type: Literal[1] = 1
    payload: Transaction2930Payload = Transaction2930Payload()

@dataclass
class Transaction1559Payload:
    chain_id: int = 0
    signer_nonce: int = 0
    max_priority_fee_per_gas: int = 0
    max_fee_per_gas: int = 0
    gas_limit: int = 0
    destination: int = 0
    amount: int = 0
    payload: bytes = bytes()
    access_list: List[Tuple[int, List[int]]] = field(default_factory=list)
    signature_y_parity: bool = False
    signature_r: int = 0
    signature_s: int = 0

@dataclass
class Transaction1559Envelope:
    type: Literal[2] = 2
    payload: Transaction1559Payload = Transaction1559Payload()

Transaction2718 = Union[Transaction1559Envelope, Transaction2930Envelope]

Transaction = Union[TransactionLegacy, Transaction2718]
```